# How to generate icon for onesignal using ionic

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I need generate the icon for one signal notification.

I tried to this

Add a file to your hooks directory inside the after_prepare folder called 030_copy_android_notification_icons.js

Put the following code in it:

```
var filestocopy = [{
    "resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png":
        "platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png"
}, {
    "resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png":
        "platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png"
}, {
    "resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png":
        "platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png"
}, {
    "resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png":
        "platforms/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png"
}, {
    "resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png":
        "platforms/android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png"
} ];

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// no need to configure below
var rootdir = process.argv[2];

filestocopy.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        var val = obj[key];
        var srcfile = path.join(rootdir, key);
        var destfile = path.join(rootdir, val);
        //console.log("copying "+srcfile+" to "+destfile);
        var destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
        if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
            fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
                fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
        }
    });
});
```

I have no idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with same issue. Your way is correct, putting `030_copy_android_notification_icons.js` file under `{root}/hooks/after_prepare`. Also note that, filename is not important.

Then to run script you need to run below comment:

```
ionic cordova prepare android
```

With this, your script will be run. But maybe your problem may be similar to mine. If you use windows, while coping files from `resources/android/icon/` to `platforms/android/res/`, because of missing of target folders, script is not able to copy operation. That's why a simple code should be added to code.

```
var destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
if (!fs.existsSync(destdir)){
  fs.mkdirSync(destdir);
}
```